# Tokenizing a String to Pass as char * into execve()

Tags: c, pointers, tokenize, arrays, execve

My knowledge of C is *very* limited. I'm trying to tokenize a String passed to a server from a client, because I want to use passed arguments to`execve`. The arguments passed via`buffer`needs to be copied to`*argv` and tokenized such that`buffer`'s tokens can be accessed with`argv[0]`, `argv[1]`, etc. Obviously I'm doing something incorrectly.

```
n = read(sockfd, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
strcpy(*argv, buffer);
printf("buffer:%s\n", buffer);
printf("argv:%s\n", *argv);
printf("argv[0]:%s\n", argv[0]);
printf("argv[1]:%s\n", argv[1]);
*argv = strtok_r(*argv, " ", argv);
printf("argv:%s\n", *argv);

i = fork();
if (i < 0) {
    //Close socket on fork error.
    perror("fork");
    exit(-1);
} else if (i == 0) {
    //execve on input args
    execve(argv[0], &argv[0], 0);
    exit(0);
} else {
    wait(&status);
    //close(sockfd);
}
```

Passing the arguments "/bin/date -u" with the above code gives an output of:

```
buffer:/bin/date -u

argv:/bin/date -u

argv[0]:/bin/date -u

argv[1]:(null)
```

What I what is an output of:

```
buffer:/bin/date -u

argv:/bin/date -u

argv[0]:/bin/date

argv[1]:-u
```

I tried using`strtok_r()`, but it didn't work as I intended. The snippet I inserted was:

```
*argv = strtok_r(*argv, " ", argv);
printf("argv:%s\n", *argv);
```

which give an output of `argv:/bin/date`.

Thanks in advanced, SO.

Edit: I don't have to explicitly tokenize`buffer`like I have above. Any way to get arguments from the client passed to the server works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, there are several issues you are dealing with. The first being the choice of `argv` as the varable you are writing buffer to. While it is just an array of pointers, you generally consider `argv` as the array holding the arguments passed **to** the instant process, not as a variable to modify. However, that is really semantics, there is no prohibition from doing it that I know of. However, you cannot tokenize `*argv` while at the same time assigning the tokens to `*argv` because `strtok_r` modifies `*argv` during the process.

Beyond that, the real issue appears to be the use of `strtok_r`. Take a look at `man strtok_r`. In order to tokenize a string, you need to make **repeated** calls to `strtok_r` in order to extract all tokens. The first call to `strtok_r` using the first argument (*argv...) merely extracts the **first** token. In order to complete the extraction, you must pass `NULL` as the first argument until all tokens have been extacted. Additionally, the string you are extracting tokens from is modified by calls to `strtok_r` and should not be used following extraction. Generally a copy of the string is made to preserve the original if it will be needed later.

In your code you call `strtok_r` only once E.g:

```
*argv = strtok_r(*argv, " ", argv);  // extracts the first token and modifies *argv
```

If your intent is to extract all strings, then you will need to make repeated calls to `strtok_r` something like:

```
char *token = malloc (sizeof (token) * 128); // or something large enough to hold the tokens

token = strtok_r(*argv, " ", argv);
if (token)
    printf (" token: %s\n", token);

while ((token = strtok_r (NULL, " ", argv)) != NULL)
{
    printf (" token: %s\n", token);
}
```

You can capture the individual tokens in however you like in order to pass them to `execve`. However, you are not going to be able to strip tokes out of `argv` while at the same time writing back to `argv`. As indicated above, `argv` is modified by `strtok_r` during extraction, so you will need a separate array to hold the tokens. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The `strtok()` and `strtok_r()` functions return one token at a time. They maintain state between calls and you need to call them in a loop to split a string into tokens. Also they modify the buffer passed as the first argument in-place, so you need to copy it.

Let me show you an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_CMD_SIZE 1024
#define MAX_ARG_COUNT 10

main()
{
    const char *command = "/bin/test arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4 arg5";

    /* Allocate a buffer for tokenization.
     * the strtok_r() function modifies this buffer in-place and return pointers
     * to strings located inside this buffer. */
    char cmd_buf[MAX_CMD_SIZE] = { 0 };
    strncpy(cmd_buf, command, sizeof(cmd_buf));

    /* This strtok_r() call puts '\0' after the first token in the buffer,
     * It saves the state to the strtok_state and subsequent calls resume from that point. */
    char *strtok_state = NULL;
    char *filename = strtok_r(cmd_buf, " ", &strtok_state);
    printf("filename = %s\n", filename);

    /* Allocate an array of pointers.
     * We will make them point to certain locations inside the cmd_buf. */
    char *args[MAX_ARG_COUNT] = { NULL };

    /* loop the strtok_r() call while there are tokens and free space in the array */
    size_t current_arg_idx;
    for (current_arg_idx = 0; current_arg_idx < MAX_ARG_COUNT; ++current_arg_idx) {
        /* Note that the first argument to strtok_r() is NULL.
         * That means resume from a point saved in the strtok_state. */
        char *current_arg = strtok_r(NULL, " ", &strtok_state);
        if (current_arg == NULL) {
            break;
        }

        args[current_arg_idx] = current_arg;
        printf("args[%d] = %s\n", current_arg_idx, args[current_arg_idx]);
    }
}
```

The output of the example above is:

```
filename = /bin/test
args[0] = arg1
args[1] = arg2
args[2] = arg3
args[3] = arg4
args[4] = arg5
```

Note that I put `filename` and `args` into separate variables to illustrate a difference between the first call and the subsequent calls. For `execve()` you normally want to put them into a single array and call it like `execve(argv[0], argv, NULL);` because the filename is supposed to be the first element in `argv`.